# How to format textbox field in Access form to show data the same as in imported file to the table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, textbox, ms-office

I have a textbox, which is presenting data from one field in selected recordset. This field contains comments made by user in Excel file, which is later imported to Access table. Each comment is made in separete line and in each it looks ok. Textbox present it as one line, but when I export it to Excel again it looks ok in that new excel.

I have tried changing textbox into rich text format. I have also create other textbox, in which I am able to insert comments and then it looks good.

Textbox source code:

```
sSql = SELECT LogID, 1Comment, 2Comment, Author 
sSql = sSql & " FROM tblGeneralLog" 
sSql = sSql & " WHERE LogID= " & Me.ID &

Forms![frmMain_CommentAdd]![txtboxComment2].Value = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSql).Fields(2).Value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably, in Excel you don't have a "full new line" (CR + LF). Thus, try:

```
Forms![frmMain_CommentAdd]![txtboxComment2].Value = Replace(CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSql).Fields(2).Value, vbCr, vbCrLf)
```

or:

```
Forms![frmMain_CommentAdd]![txtboxComment2].Value = Replace(CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sSql).Fields(2).Value, vbLf, vbCrLf)
```

Comment: Excel uses `vbLf`, so it's the second one.

Comment: Yes it was that! Thanks for quick reply!